# can i use removeAllCachedResponses frequently in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am facing a problem in UIWebView, My UIWebView has large content with images and text..

My iPad App has a UITableView to show the listing (in the left side) and a UIWebView(right side) for showing the detail.

When a cell is tapped, a URL is loaded in the UIWebView. So when i select each cell in the UITableView the UIWebView load its HTML contents.

After a few clicks my App Hangs without crashing. I get an **webcore error**. So to fix this i use the below line of code.

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

I added this line after selected cell in the UITableView, then only i am loading the URL in UIWebView. Now i solved this Hang issue.

**Note:** I want to know, whether i can use **removeAllCachedResponses** before loading the URL in UIWebView.

crash log:

```
Thread 26 WebCore: LocalStorage
malloc: *** mmap(size=1048576) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region securely
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```